# How do you get only product links from BeautifulSoup result

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.namesite.com'
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.namesite.com/genclik-kitaplari')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='box col-12 text-center')
productlinks = []

for item in productlist:
     for link in item.find_all ('a', href=True):
      print(link['href'])
```

I try to get the links of the books on this page, but there are 2 more links besides the book links. How can I get only book links?

The links I want are the first link of the products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict by using the appropriate classes from the multi-valued class of each of the cards

```
product_links = [baseurl + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.text-description.detailLink')]
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.bkmkitap.com'
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.bkmkitap.com/genclik-kitaplari')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
product_links = [baseurl + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.text-description.detailLink')]
```

Comment: smooth. looks like it picks up duplicate links when I run ,but if I take the whole class with soup.select('.fl.col-12.text-description.detailLink') it looks correct.

Comment: Thank you for answers I am new in python I dont understand how to add this line to my code.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeon I added an additional class

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using `html.parser` do the same as `xml`. Is the later one faster? Is it possible to use either of them or there is a difference?

Comment: @YasserKhalil https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser